# How to disable certain standard log4j2 plugin

Tags: android, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to use Log4j2 on Android, it fails with the following stacktrace. Android has no javax.naming support, and I don't really need this plugin in log4j2.
How can I disable Log4j2 JNDI plugin? (Or any other standard plugin)

```
07-04 11:36:17.088    1573-1573/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:144)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:80)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:72)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:473)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:418)
            at com.altius.epos2.MyActivity.<clinit>(MyActivity.java:17)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:75)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:99)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:29)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:63)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:144)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:80)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:72)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:473)
            at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:418)
            at com.altius.epos2.MyActivity.<clinit>(MyActivity.java:17)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using RC-2? Please raise this on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker so it will be fixed for the upcoming 2.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying the same thing and encountered a similar problem with JNDI, i created a JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-703 with my code and the stacktrace i obtained.